# query to limit repeated values in columns - SQL

Tags: sql

Hi there wondering if anyone can help me, this might not be the best description but I will try my best. I have a table which has a column that has many repeating values.

```
COL1|COL2|COL3
1    data data
1    data data
1    data data
2    data data
2    data data
```

I want a query that returns only 1 of the repeated values of col1. So the query does this.

```
COL1
1
2
```

Is this even possible and how would I be able to do it?

Comment: See the DISTINCT keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` keywords after `SELECT` statement

As in

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...
```

Comment: Will work fine as long as COL2 and COL3 only contain duplicates (for each COL1.)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first column, then:

```
select distinct col1
from t;
```

This may not do what you expect if you have multiple columns.

If you want complete rows, but only one per value, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```